# How to iterate a map that contains another map with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, dictionary, iteration

I have this json called **data**:

[image]

Like you can see, this map contains another map (listInfo).

I iterate it with:

```
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    alert(value);
};
```

The alert print all values (1, Reunion, 15/06/2015, and so on) but when arrives to listInfo it prints, rightly, `[object Object]`

How can I solve this problem? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
function loop(data) {
    $.each(data, function (key, value) {
        if(typeof value === "object")
            loop(value);
        else
            alert(value);
    });
}
loop(data);
```